# When using ASP.NET MVC 3 with EF 4.1 Code First, I can only edit the main table, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, code-first

A brief description of what I am doing. I am creating a rather crude IS Asset tracking database using ASP MVC 3 and EF Code First approach. I can create a new asset. I can view the details on an asset. I can even display the edit view and edit the AssetTag. However the record will not update any of the other fields. If I edit the LocationName for instance. It will act like it is posting and return me to the Index view, but the record never actually posts the change.

I have created the Model below

```
public class AssetModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string AssetTag { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Hardware Hardware { get; set; }
    public virtual Software Software { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}



public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
}
public class Hardware
{
    public int HardwareId { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }

}

public class Software
{
    public int SoftwareId { get; set; }
    public string PublisherName { get; set; }
    public string SoftwarePackageName { get; set; }
    public string SoftwarePackageVersion { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsVolumeLicense { get; set; } // as in "Yes this is a Vol. Lic. Agreement"
    public LicenseAgreement LicenseAgreement { get; set; }
}

public class LicenseAgreement 
{
    public int LicId { get; set; }
    public string VolumeLicenseAgreementCompany { get; set; }
    public string AgreementIdentifier { get; set; } 
    public DateTime VolumeLicenseStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime VolumeLicenseExpirationDate { get; set; }
    public Int16 NumberOfLicenses { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    // may remove this at some time and pull from Active Directory.
    // for now we take the easy route.
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have this DbDataSet that uses the AssetModel above:

```
public class AssetContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AssetModel> Assets { get; set; }
 }
```

In my AssetController I have this for Edit:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        AssetModel assetmodel = db.Assets.Find(id);
        return View(assetmodel);
    }
    //
    // POST: /Asset/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(AssetModel assetmodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(assetmodel).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(assetmodel);
    }
```

And here is the Edit.cshtml

```
@model ISHelpDesk.Models.AssetModel

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
  }

 <h2>Edit</h2>
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Asset")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>AssetModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssetTag)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssetTag)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssetTag)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location.LocationName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Location.LocationName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location.LocationName)
    </div>

    </fieldset>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save"</p>
 }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I am using SQL Server CE as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `AssetContext` should be

```
public class AssetContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AssetModel> Assets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Hardware> Hardwares { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Software> Softwares { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LicenseAgreement> LicenseAgreements { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

this is registering each of your classes as a table in the `DbContext`, what you had before showed your `DbContext` consists only of `AssetModel`

**Update:** The issue may be that when you get to the post method of the edit, the Asset is no longer associated with the database Asset it was originally loaded from, have a go at changing it to

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    AssetModel assetmodel = db.Assets.Find(id);
    return View(assetmodel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
{
    AssetModel assetmodel = db.Assets.Find(id);

    if (TryUpdateModel(assetmodel))
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(assetmodel);
}
```

Obviously this may not be the behaviour you want I'm just trying to see if you can get some changes persisted and go from there

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I understand what you are saying and I made that change, but still no update. As you can imagine it is frustrating.

Comment: Now that persists. Thank you. Now I have to think it through as to why. You are the Shizzle!

Answer (score 0):

Your Model classes should extend `DbContext`:

```
 public class AssetModel :DbContext{}
```

Comment: Great stab at it, but unfortunately that did not work. I was really crossing my fingers and hoping that it was something that silly. :)

Comment: Thanks, I should have posted the entire dbcontext, that was already there.

Comment: I'm really starting to think there is problem with EF Code First

Comment: I noticed that some of the properties are virtual. That will force EF to lazy load them. Have you tried to remove the virtual keyword?

Comment: Thanks again, but that was not it either. I appreciate the help though.